# parse hour minute second from date time r

Tags: r, datetime

For some reason, I've been struggling to get this right. I want to parse the hour, minute, and second part from the below string in R.

```
x <- "2019-04-27T06:40:04.000+05:30"
x<-gsub("[0-9]*-", "", x)
x<-gsub("[0-9]*T", "", x)
x<-unlist(strsplit(x, split="[.]"))[1]
x<-unlist(strsplit(x, split=":"))
```

Isn't there a way I can say?

```
as.DateTime(x, "%H")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to treat date-time objects as it is instead of using regex to extract information.

```
x <- "2019-04-27T06:40:04.000+05:30" 
as.POSIXct(x, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%T")
#[1] "2019-04-27 06:40:04"
```

and then we can use `format` to extract the details which we want

```
format(as.POSIXct(x, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%T"), "%T")
#[1] "06:40:04"

format(as.POSIXct(x, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%T"), "%H")
#[1] "06"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.. I remember trying this.. but not sure what I was missing